# Running humble on Turtlebot3

Tags: ros2, turtlebot, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I recently got a turtlebot3 burger and I only see instructions for installing foxy on it. I saw that the turtlebot3 GitHub page has humble support. Can I flash a regular Ubuntu 22 on the tb3 RPi and then build the turtlebot3 repo from source?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411908/running-humble-on-turtlebot3/) by [MrOCW](https://answers.ros.org/users/95995/mrocw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2023-01-27

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [proto](https://answers.ros.org/users/142343/proto/) on 2023-03-18**:
Hey!
I am also trying to run ros2 humble on tb3, still confused what image to flash on the rpi4, as the available image is of ros foxy.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2023-03-20**:
Please don't ask questions as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Flashing Ubuntu 22, installing ROS2 Humble, and building tb3 humble from source works

---

Originally posted by [MrOCW](https://answers.ros.org/users/95995/mrocw/) with karma: 58 on 2023-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment TurtleBot3 Does not support Humble It supports Kinetic Melodic, Noetic, Dashing, and Foxy. You can see the installation list here: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/#pc-setup

It comes from:

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/emanual/blob/master/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick_start/quick_start.md

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2023-03-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the newest ROS 2 on the older TB2:

- https://github.com/igrak34/TurtleBot2-on-ROS2

So if you can manage to build the drivers from source for TB3 you should be good to go. Perhaps more advanced packages could be harder to compile, we could help you with them.

EDIT:

For these packages to work you have to set up source build of the `kobuki-base`, clone these in your `ros2_ws/src`, with `rosdep install` before building them - I have these commands on hand for my setup:

#### ROS 2 setup after installation (https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians)

```
echo "source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
sudo apt install python3-colcon-common-extensions
echo "source /usr/share/colcon_cd/function/colcon_cd.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "export _colcon_cd_root=/opt/ros/humble/" >> ~/.bashrc
echo "source /usr/share/colcon_argcomplete/hook/colcon-argcomplete.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

#### Nav2 binaries

```
   sudo apt install ros-humble-navigation2
   sudo apt install ros-humble-nav2-bringup
   sudo apt install ros-humble-turtlebot3*
   sudo apt install ros-humble-turtle*
   export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
   export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros/humble/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models
```

#### Test launch

```
  ros2 launch nav2_bringup tb3_simulation_launch.py
```

#### ROS 2 workspace for sources

```
cd ~/tb2_ros2_nav2/
mkdir -p ros2_ws/src
cd ~/tb2_ros2_nav2/ros2_ws/src
```

#### Clone these Kobuki packages

```
git clone https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_core.git
git clone https://github.com/kobuki-base/velocity_smoother.git
git clone https://github.com/kobuki-base/cmd_vel_mux.git
git clone https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros_interfaces.git
git clone https://github.com/kobuki-base/kobuki_ros.git
```

#### Important! Install dependencies (ECL libraries, etc.)

```
cd ~/tb2_ros2_nav2/ros2_ws/
sudo rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro humble -y
```

#### Build Kobuki packages

```
colcon build --symlink-install
```

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2023-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Djinn](https://answers.ros.org/users/142720/djinn/) on 2023-04-10**:
Hey, I am also trying to use ROS2 Humble on a TurtleBot2, also built it from source and cloned https://github.com/igrak34/TurtleBot2-on-ROS2 on it. Tried to use `colcon build` on it but there were some packages which were missing so I keep cloning them until i got the message that  ecl_linear_algebra is needed which is only available for ROS2 foxy. How did you bypass this problem?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-04-10**:
I have updated my answer with a short list of commands, it looks like you have some missing dependencies. Please ask a separate question with your errors if these are not sufficient.

**Comment by [Djinn](https://answers.ros.org/users/142720/djinn/) on 2023-04-17**:
Thank you very much for your answer! I do have some questions which I have stated in a different [thread](https://answers.ros.org/question/414453/turtlebot2-on-ros2-humble/) and would highly appreciate if you could take a look.